# Jquery don't work in firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox

I'm a newbie to jquery, but have managed to make a show-function and hover on a div work in my site. Unfortunately it only works in Chrome and Safari and not Firefox:

http://kommunal.dk/konference/konference.html#

I know my coding is somewhat a mess, nonetheless any reply would be appreciated. Here goes:

On a div I have:

```
<div id="tilmeldingknap" >Tilmelding</div><br />

    <script type="text/jscript">

    $('#tilmeldingknap').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','auto');
        }
    );

    $('#tilmeldingknap').click(
        function() {
             $('#konference-tilmelding').show('slow');
             $('#tilmeldingknap').hide(); 
             return false;
        }
    );
</script>
```

In my header I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: A note on your page - a lot of the links point towards local resources (`file:///Macintosh HD/...`). You should fix those to point to the real web resources!

Comment: You have an error on the file konferencetilmelding.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use jQuery before you link it and that hide should be in a document ready event handler.

SCRIPT5009: '$' is undefined 
konference.html, line 16 character 6
SCRIPT1010: Expected identifier 
konferencetilmelding.js, line 1 character 31
SCRIPT5009: 'getTMqs' is undefined 
konference.html, line 515 character 1

from your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">


     $('#konference-tilmelding').hide("fast");

</script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/generelle.js"></script>
2

    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/jqModal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/fade-plugin.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/konferencetilmelding.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/kommunal.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/jscript">
```

should be

```
<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove `type="text/jscript"`, or use `type="text/javascript"`. [JScript](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hbxc2t98%28VS.85%29.aspx) is Microsoft's implementation of ES3. JavaScript is not JScript.

Answer (score 0):

You have some invalid HTML there,

```
<div id="tilmeldingknap" >Tilmelding</div><br />
```

Comment: No, it's not - thats the fixed version. It's invalid in the OP's post, or at least it was before he edited it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Many of the links are homed on your PC;

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/jqModal.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have loads of local files linked in your code, make sure all your css / js links are relative so you don't get this problem.

For example you should change:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="file:///Macintosh HD/Users/jakobthuemoes/Documents/Webdesign/Kommunal/web/portal/js/generelle.js"></script>
```

To:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../js/generelle.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

All together correct:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

```
<div id="tilmeldingknap" >Tilmelding</div><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tilmeldingknap').hover(function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','pointer')
    ;}, function() {
        $(this).css('cursor','auto');
    });
    $('#tilmeldingknap').click(function() {
       $('#konferencetilmelding').show('slow');$('#tilmeldingknap').hide();        
       return false;
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the first lines be:

```
<div id="tilmeldingknap" >Tilmelding</div><br />

<script type="text/javascript">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#tilmeldingknap').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','pointer');
        }, 
        function() {
            $(this).css('cursor','auto');
        }
    );
});

$('#tilmeldingknap').click(
        function() {
             $('#konference-tilmelding').show('slow');
             $('#tilmeldingknap').hide(); 
             return false;
        }
    );
```